# How to run samplers/sets of samplers in random order

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I have a "Thread Group" which has 15 "HTTP Requests".I want to execute these request randomly, they are executing in a sequence like one by one

```
HTTP Request 1
HTTP Request 2
HTTP Request 3
.
.
HTTP Request 15
```

I want them to be executed randomly like

```
HTTP Request 7
HTTP Request 2
HTTP Request 15
.
.
HTTP Request 3
```

How can I achieve this?

Second question: I want to make sets of certain requests and then want them to run randomly.For Instance I have this 3 requests set, Call it 'Set A'

```
1- New Subject Request
2- Enroll in Subject Request
3- Delete Enrolment Request
```

Then I have this another set, Call it 'Set B'

```
1- New Student Request
2- Student Class Request
3- Delete Student Class
```

Now I want these two sets(A, B) to be executed in random sequence but requests within these Sets must run in same sequence as given.

How Can it be done? How can I make Sets of certain requests and How to make them run in random sequence but requests in a certain sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute samplers randomly by putting them under [Random Order Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller):

> The Random Order Controller is much like a Simple Controller in that it will execute each child element at most once, but the order of execution of the nodes will be random.

To execute sets of samplers randomly put Simple Controllers with samplers under Random Order Controller (it will randomize only direct children):

```
Random Order Controller
  Simple Controller A
    New Subject Request
    Enroll in Subject Request
    Delete Enrolment Request
  Simple Controller B
    New Student Request
    Student Class Request
    Delete Student Class
```

Comment: You are simply Awesome! :)